# Django - How to work with `auth_permission` Model

Tags: python, django, models

Django make its own permission models, like `auth_permission`.
I want to add new permission doing this by code.

How I normally add something to a table

```
from .models import Model

mdl, succeeded = Model.objects.get_or_create(
    field=value,
    field=value
)
mdl.save()
```

But to call the `auth_permission` Model, I have to import the model first.
Only I can't find how this Model is called.

So do one of you guys know what to import to call this Model?

Answer (score 1):

You can import the permission model with

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
```

However, if you want to create custom permissions, the [documented approach](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions) is to add permissions to a model. Django will then create the permissions when you run `manage.py migrate`.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("can_do_something", "Can do something"),
        )
```